# RecyclerView.Adapter не всегда обновляет данные

Tags: android, adapter, recyclerview

В методе onActivityResult меняю исходные данные, которые поступили в адаптер в момент создания фрагмента. Работает, почему-то, в 70% случаев, перестает работать после повторного нажатия на вкладку в Drawer'e с фрагментом или после перехода/возвращения с других Activity других фрагментов. В Log выводит, что действительно получает нужные данные, и размер массива данных, которые поступают в адаптер, такой, какой и должен быть после обновления. Визуально ничего не меняется. Код адаптера:

```
 public class LakesRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LakesRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Lake> lakes;

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView image;
        public CardView cardView;
        public TextView name;
        public TextView description;
        public CheckBox popular;
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image_list_item);
            cardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name_list_item);
            description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description_list_item);
            popular = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.popular_checkbox_list_item);
        }
    }

    public LakesRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Lake> lakes) {
        this.lakes = lakes;
    }

    @Override
    public LakesRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.lake_list_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Lake current = lakes.get(position);

        holder.name.setText(current.getName());
        holder.description.setText
                (current.getLocation().latitude + " " + current.getLocation().longitude);
        holder.popular.setChecked(current.isPopular());
        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), LakeItemTabActivity.class);
                i.putExtra(LakeItemTabActivity.EXTRA_UUID, current.getId());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lakes.size();
    }
}
```

Код onOptionsItemSelected (здесь происходит переход на Activity, по возвращении с которой данные должны обновиться)

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_search:
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ChooseRegionActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_LAKE_REGION);
            return true;
        default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Код onActivityResult:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (data == null) {return;}
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_LAKE_REGION && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        int countryCode = data.getIntExtra(EXTRA_COUNTRY_ID, 0);
        int regionCode = data.getIntExtra(EXTRA_REGION_ID, 0);
        lakes = LakesLab.get(getActivity()).getLakesByCountryAndRegion(countryCode, regionCode);
        lakesAdapter = new LakesRecyclerAdapter(lakes);
        lakesRecyclerView.setAdapter(lakesAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте после setAdapter поставить lakesRecyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: вы на самом деле не меняете значения в адаптере, а просто создаете новый адаптер каждый раз. Это просто замечание.

Answer (score 1):

В адаптер нужно добавить метод

```
public void setLikesList(ArrayList<Lake> lakes){
    this.lakes=lakes;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

И в onActivityResult вместо:

```
lakesAdapter = new LakesRecyclerAdapter(lakes);
lakesRecyclerView.setAdapter(lakesAdapter);
```

вызывать

```
lakesAdapter.setLikesList(lakes);
```

Comment: работает всё так же через раз.